# Query data from SmartStore(Local) using Where Condition

Tags: smartstore

Im storing Different types of Notes inside the SmartStore , currently im able to retrieve all the data from the smartnote table , but i need to use the Where condition to Retrieve a type of note. so i tried using

QuerySpec.buildSmartQuerySpec("select {Note:type} from {Note}" Where type='Uncategorized'", 1)
    but its not working im getting null value as result, so i tried using

```
    smartStore.query(QuerySpec.buildExactQuerySpec(
                    "Note","type","Uncategorized","type", QuerySpec.Order.ascending,1),0);
```

but im getting null as result , What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this Query Works to select using Where Condition

```
'JSONArray result1 = smartStore.query(QuerySpec.buildSmartQuerySpec
                ("select {Note:subject},{Note:note} from {Note} WHERE {Note:Type}='Uncategorized'", 2000), 0);'
```